# intelliJ IDEA "Overrides method" warning with Java 8 lambda expressions

Tags: intellij-idea, compiler-warnings

I get a warning "Overrides method in java.util.function.Function" when using lambda expressions like 
`new Vector<String>().stream().map(String::toString);` but as far as I know this is just normal lambda usage. How can I get rid of this warning without removing legitimate override warnings?

I use intelliJ IDEA 2016.1.3 with OpenJDK 8 on Gnome on Arch Linux.

Comment: Not an error, surprise!!! This is clearly another great moment in UX design!  In general shouldn't use a well establish color pattern (green good, red bad/error) for informational only meta--especially in a tool like an IDE.  Why not light purple or grey?

Comment: Turns out this is on their radar and have plans to change it to not be red at some point: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-147324

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Do you mean the icon in the editor gutter? That is not a warning, but an indication and allows navigation to the super method using the mouse. The icon(s) can be disabled in `File | Settings | Editor | General | Gutter Icons`.

Comment: I had a similar reaction the first time I saw the symbol since they used red for the icon which usually means warning/error.

Comment: Same here.  I saw the red icon and said "What is THIS error now?"  It is a feature, not a bug!

Comment: For lambda usage it's totally redundant, if it shows up for every lambda usage it's just noise.  Also it makes setting breakpoints a PITA.

Comment: Thank you! That was such an annoying and unhelpful icon.

Comment: Looks like at least 25 other devs found a RED X MARK in the gutter a problem.  Come on IntelliJ! Make it blue....and don't use an X ffs